# ¿Cómo puedo hacer una sobrecarga de método en javascript, evitando la recursividad?

Tags: javascript, clase, recursión

Supongamos que tengo un objeto:

```
var miObjeto = function() { this.text = 'hola mundo'; }
miObjeto.prototype.agregarAlgo = function(sufijo) { return (this.text + sufijo); };
```

¿Cómo puedo sobrecargar/sobreescribir la función de manera que se preserve el `this` pero que la función no se vuelva recursiva? Al escribirlo de la  siguiente forma...

```
var _instancia = new miObjeto();
_instancia.prototype.agregarAlgo = function(text) { 
    console.log('codigo inyectado');
    _instancia.prototype.agregarAlgo(text); 
}
```

La función se ejecuta recursivamente. Y haciendolo de la siguiente forma...

```
var _instancia = new miObjeto();
var _oldfunc = _instance.agregarAlgo;

_instancia.prototype.agregarAlgo = function(text) { 
    console.log('codigo inyectado');
    _oldfunc(text); 
}
```

Me arroja un error en el que `this` no encuentra la variable `text`, como si cambiara de 'scope'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dado que quieres hacer un overload directo y no por herencia prototípica,
hay que tener en cuenta que:

```
 this.text
```

No es una propiedad del prototipo, sino de la instancia. El constructor `miObjeto`  no tiene cómo saber qué es `this.text` hasta que alguien lo instancie. Para mayor abundamiento, es como si al instanciar se hiciera:

```
var MiObjeto = function(nombre) {
   this.nombre = nombre;
}

// necesariamente undefined
console.log(MiObjeto.prototype.nombre);
```

En contraposición, si el prototipo tuviese la propiedad:

```
MiObjeto.prototype.nombre = 'El constructor MiObjeto';
```

Esta sería visible para sí mismo y para todas sus instancias.

Ahora bien, qué pasaría si al instanciar se sobreescribiera tal propiedad?

```
function MiObjeto(nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}
```

En ese caso:

```
let _instancia= new MiObjeto('la instancia de MiObjeto');

console.log({
    nombreInstancia: _instancia.nombre, // 'la instancia de MiObjeto'
    nombreObjeto: MiObjeto.prototype.nombre // 'El constructor MiObjeto'
});
```

De manera que declarando en el protipo un accesor del nombre

```
MiObjeto.prototype.getNombre = function() {
  return this.nombre;
};
```

Y una función que distinguiera la propiedad de instancia vs la propiedad del prototipo:

```
MiObjeto.prototype.quienEsQuien = function() {
  console.log(`Hola. Soy ${this.getNombre()}`);
  console.log(`Y vengo de ${Object.getPrototypeOf(this).getNombre()}`);
};
```

Tendríamos:

```
var _instancia = new MiObjeto('soy una instancia');
_instancia.quienEsQuien();
// Hola. Soy la instancia de MiObjeto
// Y vengo de El constructor MiObjeto
```

Nótese que declarar ese `quienEsQuien` en la instancia

```
_instancia.quienEsQuien = function() {
  console.log(`Hola. Soy ${this.getNombre()}`);
  console.log(`Y vengo de ${Object.getPrototypeOf(this).getNombre()}`);
};
```

no altera el funcionamiento... (mal que mal, en esta modalidad igual estamos preguntándole a la instancia cómo se llama y de dónde viene)

Finalmente, una sobrecarga de `quienEsQuien` puede hacerse incluso sobre la marcha:

```js
var MiObjeto = function(nombre) {
  this.nombre = nombre;
}
MiObjeto.prototype.nombre = 'El constructor MiObjeto';
MiObjeto.prototype.getNombre =function() {
  return this.nombre;
} 
MiObjeto.prototype.quienEsQuien = function() {
  console.log(`Hola. Soy ${this.getNombre()}`);
  console.log(`Y vengo de ${Object.getPrototypeOf(this).getNombre()}`);
};

var _instancia= new MiObjeto('la instancia de MiObjeto');


_instancia.quienEsQuien();

_instancia.quienEsQuien = function() {
  console.log(`Hola. Sigo siendo ${this.getNombre()}`);
  console.log(`Y sigo viniendo de ${Object.getPrototypeOf(this).getNombre()}`);
};

_instancia.quienEsQuien();
```

Vale la pena señalar que `_instancia.prototype` no significa nada. Lo que tiende a confundirse es que el prototipo del constructor está en `_instancia.__proto__`. (pero no es bonito interactuar con `__proto__`, por eso usé `getPrototypeOf`). Además, Esto puede comprobarse (y aprovechando, mirar otro detalle) con

```
console.log({
 '_instancia.prototype': _instancia.prototype, // esto es undefined
 '_instancia.__proto__': _instancia.__proto__, // este es un objeto
 '_instancia.constructor': _instancia.constructor // esta es una función
});
```

¿Cuándo puede usarse `X.prototype.metodo` para sobrecargar la "clase" original? Cuando se trata de un constructor que hereda de `MiObjeto`. En ese escenario (que no debieras dejar sin explorar) puedes partir de `MiObjeto`, heredar en `MiObjetoJunior`, instanciar en `_instanciaJunior` y aún así acceder a la propiedad de la instancia, del prototipo directo y del prototipo original.

```js
var MiObjeto = function(nombre) {
  this.nombre = nombre;
}
MiObjeto.prototype.nombre = 'El constructor MiObjeto';
MiObjeto.prototype.getNombre =function() {
  return this.nombre;
} 
MiObjeto.prototype.quienEsQuien = function() {
  console.log(`Hola. Soy ${this.getNombre()}`);
  console.log(`Y vengo de ${Object.getPrototypeOf(this).getNombre()}`);
};


var MiObjetoJunior = function(nombre) {
   this.nombre=nombre;
};
MiObjetoJunior.prototype = Object.create(MiObjeto.prototype);
MiObjetoJunior.prototype.nombre = 'El constructor MiObjetoJunior';


MiObjetoJunior.prototype.quienEsQuien = function() {
  console.log(`Hola. Soy ${this.getNombre()}`);
  console.log(`Y vengo de ${Object.getPrototypeOf(this).getNombre()}`);
  console.log(`Quien a su vez viene de ${Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(this)).getNombre()}`);
};

var _instanciaJunior = new MiObjetoJunior(' la instancia junior');
_instanciaJunior.quienEsQuien();
```

Answer (score 0):

Quizás creando una clase de esta forma, te pueda servir

```js
function miObjeto () {
  this.text = 'hola mundo';
  this.agregarAlgo = function(text) {
    this.text = text;
  }
}
var mio = new miObjeto();
console.log(mio.text); // -> hola mundo

mio.agregarAlgo('hello world');
console.log(mio.text); // -> hello world
```

Comment: realmente el problema no radica en la la creación de la clase, ni en la salida del texto, sino en la alteracion del proceso escrito en la funcion, esto nace de la necesidad de sobreescribir metodos de un plugin cuyo codigo no puedo editar por multiples razones, pero si puedo utilizar el objeto, instanciarlo y queria saber si podia sobreescribirlo, sin que pierda la funcionalidad que tenia, previamente. es decir inyectar codigo en la funcion...

Comment: @isLiz y qué plugin es el que intentas modificar?